# Add and remove a class in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function, to make a visual object come on and off, on and off, as the user clicks on it. Then add a click event listener in the class, called button `btn-sauce`.

So far my code doesn't work :

```
function renderWhiteSauce() {
  if (element.classList) {
  element.classList.toggle("btn-sauce.active");
} else {
  var classes = element.className.split(" ");
  var i = classes.indexOf("btn-sauce.active");
  if (i >= 0)
    classes.splice(i, 1);
  else
    classes.push("btn-sauce.active");
    element.className = classes.join(" ");
}

document.querySelector('.btn-sauce.active').addEventListener('click', () => {
  state.sauce = !state.sauce;
  renderEverything();
});
```

Comment: You should use the `classList` property rather than `className`, this makes it much easier to search, add, and remove. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: The function is named `renderWhiteSauce` but you're calling `renderEverything`. And where do you set `element` and `state`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add and remove classes with methods classList.add('classname') and classList.remove('classname'). Define class which makes btn active and just add or remove it.

```
const elem = document.querySelector('.btn-sauce')
elem.addEventListener('click', () => { 
 if(elem.className.indexOf('className') < 0) {
   elem.classList.add('className')
 } else {
   elem.classList.remove('className')
 }  
 });
```

Comment: `elem.classList.toggle` in the OP's code does the same thing in one line. The OP's solution is actually more complete because it does this but also accounts for older browsers that don't support `classList`.

Answer (score 0):

`btn-sauce` and `active` are two separate classes, but you are writing your code like they are one. Remove `btn-sauce.` (including the dot) from everything above the querySelector line and you will be able to toggle the `active` class on and off.

If the element is not "active" to begin with, you should also change `document.querySelector('.btn-sauce.active')` to `document.querySelector('.btn-sauce')`.

One last note, you are calling `renderEverything()` in your click handler, which I assume is another function that calls `renderWhiteSauce()`, but I thought I'd mention it in case this was just a typo and they were meant to be the same function.